# Fill canvas with rectangles of appropriate size

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a canvas (Im using a graphics object for my form in this case) and it has a height and a width. For the sake of simplicity, let's suppose height and width are the same. I want to fill this with rectangles, these need to have a size so that x amount of rectangles fit in one row on the canvas.

Here is what I've tried to far:

```cs
float rect_len = this.Height / 20; // In this case i want to have 20 rectangles on the canvas
for (int x = 0; x < this.Width; x++)
{
       for (int y = 0; y < this.Height; y++)
       {
            g.FillRectangle(brush, x* node_len, y* node_len, node_len, node_len);
       }
}
```

Here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af8GR.png) of that. As you can see, at the edges the rectangles are cut of.

Comment: What is `this`?  What are the `Height` and `Width` property types?

Comment: What is the dimension of this form?

Comment: Use the ClientRectangle dimensions instead.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 The dimensions of the form are stored as this.Height and this.Width, they're both 250

Comment: @LarsTech I still get the same problem.

Comment: @CostaricanSaerh I asked what their types are.  Are they integers?  If so you're using integer division, not floating point division.

Comment: My comment wasn't necessarily meant as an answer.  Width and Height will include any border "fluff" if the form has a border, so always refer to the ClientRectangle or ClientSize when dealing with your form's canvas.

Comment: @LarsTech Casting the values into floats fixed my problem in the prototype, but using ClientRectangle actually solved the same problem in my acutall project. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
float rect_len = this.Height / 20; // 250 divided by 20 is 12 (integer division)
```

You are performing an integer division here, thus losing precision on the decimal parts. Try make one of the numbers a float first:

```
float rect_len = this.Height / 20f;
```

Note: `20f` is a float literal here. Alternatively, you can also cast the height into a float, like `(float)this.Height`.